# Modifying a Promise Prototype in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Basic Explanation: I am writing a class that wraps the nodeJS mysql function. In that class I have a select function that creates a query to run. I am returning a Promise so I can easily use the .then and .catch functionality.

Question: Is there a better way of adding a .before function then this basic setup that I have here? Or is there downsides to modifying a Promise?

```js
function beforePromise(add){
    var before = [];
    
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve){

        if(typeof add !== "number"){
            throw new Error("argument 'add' is not a valid number.");
        }
        var number = 0;
        number += add;

        setTimeout(function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < before.length; i++){
                number = before[i](number);
            }

            // get the query from database

            // resolve
            resolve(number);
        }, 0);

    });

    // add the .before function
    p.before = function(callback){
        if(typeof callback === "function"){
            before.push(callback);
        }
        return p;
    };
    return p;
}

beforePromise(10)
  .before((num) => num * 1.2) // num = 12
  .before((num) => num + 2) // num = 14
  .then(num => console.log(num))// output 14
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  
beforePromise(10)
  .then((num) => console.log(num));// output 10
  
/*
beforePromise()
  .then((num) => console.log(num))
  .catch(err) => console.log(err));
  */
```

Comment: Why do you want to go with your approach instead of `before(10).before((num) => num * 1.2).before((num) => num + 2).exec().then( ... )` ?

Comment: No, don't extend promises with your own methods.

Comment: @Bergi so you  would say returning an object similar to this `var returnObject = {
    before: () => {/* process data*/ return returnObject;},
    after: () => {/* process data*/return returnObject;},
    onError: () => {/* process data*/return returnObject;}
}` would be a better idea?

Comment: @TrevorReimer Returning a promise (or at least, your own thenable) is usually a better idea than taking callbacks, but really I don't know what your wrapper is supposed to do exactly so I cannot recommend anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the Promise is not the main problem, but the potential unexpected behaviour introduces by `setTimeout`.

If I read the code:

```
beforePromise(10)
  .before((num) => num * 1.2) // num = 12
  .before((num) => num + 2) // num = 14
  .then(num => console.log(num))// output 14
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Then to me it is not clear that I'm not allowed to do something like this

```
var obj = beforePromise(10)

var val = await someAsyncTask()
obj = obj.before((num) => num * val) 
obj = obj.before((num) => num + 2)

obj.then(num => console.log(num))// output 14
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

This would not have the expected result. So you need to describe that in the documentation and the maintainer/reviewer of the code needs to know that or look that up in the documentation.

A better approach is to have an explicit function that triggers the execution of that process.

```
before(10)
  .before((num) => num * 1.2) // num = 12
  .before((num) => num + 2) // num = 14
  .exec() // does returns the Promise and does the execution
  .then(num => console.log(num)) // output 14
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

```js
function before(add) {
  var callbacks = [];
  var obj = {
    before: before,
    exec: exec
  }


  function before(callback) {
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
      callbacks.push(callback);
    }
    return obj;
  }

  function exec() {
    if (typeof add !== "number") {
      throw new Error("argument 'add' is not a valid number.");
    }
    var number = 0;
    number += add;

    for (var i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
      number = callbacks[i](number);
    }

    return Promise.resolve(number)
  }

  return obj
}

before(10)
  .before((num) => num * 1.2) // num = 12
  .before((num) => num + 2) // num = 14
  .exec()
  .then(num => console.log(num)) // output 14
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

before(10)
  .exec()
  .then((num) => console.log(num)); // output 10
```

Comment: would I always need to use the `.exec()` or wouldn't it be enough to detect if a `.before()` was used and if not just exec anyway.

Comment: @TrevorReimer Thing is, you *can't* "detect" whether the next call in the method chain will be a `.before()` or something else

Comment: @TrevorReimer You could add a `then`  method to the object that you return, and create the real Promise at the time the `then` is called, but then you have to ensure that your object conforms to the Promise/A+ specification, otherwise you didn't gain anything with regard to maintainability. So I would go with the `exec`  approach.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks. This is what I came up with. Still working on improvements. https://jsfiddle.net/TrevorReimer/yvpur86n/18/

Comment: @TrevorReimer I really suggest to not solve it that way. What is the reason that you don't want to use the `exec` solution? It is not real overhead in writing and makes clear when the composing finished and the processing starts. Your code breaks the Promise chain and is similar to the deferred anti pattern. I don't want to say that it is not possible to get it right. But the disadvantages of this method are imho bigger than the presumed advantages.